# Errors when trying to use netstandard with Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I've been trying to make a project that will use netstandard class libraries common code however I have been unsuccessful as I keep running into errors. I have been following the post here https://oren.codes/2016/07/09/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard/ and https://xamarinhelp.com/dot-net-standard-pcl-xamarin-forms/ on how to do it. His sample I can download and run fine but when I try replicate it with his instructions I run into the error

> Your project is not referencing the ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111" framework. Add a reference to ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.  FixMyCity.Mobile    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets  140

Which I know it sounds obvious; just add `.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111` in the frameworks section of project.json but then I get this error (80% certain it's caused by adding it in since it's not there otherwise)

> Packages containing MSBuild targets and props files cannot be fully installed in projects targeting multiple frameworks. The MSBuild targets and props files have been ignored.   ...project.nuget.targets

Also when I look at the sample project, he does not target `.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111` and it works fine

This is the closest I've gotten with it so far if you would like to take a look: https://github.com/Toxicable/XamarinFormsNetstandardIssue
It's just the template project (Xamrin forms protalble) with the steps below applied

1. Run `PM> Uninstall-Package xamarin.forms -Force -RemoveDependencies on each project; IOS and Andriod first PCL last.
2. Restart VS as prompted by console
3. Add in `project.json` to each project as below
4. Try build but well it wont

**PCL project.json**

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Xamarin.Forms": "2.3.0.107",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.1": {
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8"
    },
    ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111": {}
  }
}
```

**project.Driod project.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0": {
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win": {}
  }
}
```

**project.iOS project.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0": {
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the notes on Cycle 7 Service Release 1? 

https://releases.xamarin.com/beta-release-cycle-7-service-release-1-updated/

These builds introduce compatibility with the new .NET Standard 1.6.  This in particular allows developers to consume NuGet packages that have been built against the .NET Standard 1.6.

Comment: @JonDouglasI have seen that, how ever I am unsure what that has to do with my issue, im targeting a low Net Standard since it is most compatible but will change to the highest I can to target iOS and Andriod which is 1.6 I think once the project actually builds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your project and noticed that the Xamarin Forms Portable Library was looking a little odd, you would normally see the Xamarin Forms and .NET Standard Library in your references with the blue icon.

I am not sure how it happened but here is how you fix it.

1. Remove `".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111": {}` from your project.json.
2. Unload your project
3. Edit the project file

[image]

4. Remove this line `<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile111</TargetFrameworkProfile>`
5. Change v4.5 to v5.0 `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v5.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`
6. Save the file and reload the project and it now builds without the need for Profile111 and will also show the references

[image]

Comment: That was exactly the issue, thank you very much for taking the time to point this out to be, also not sure how it occurred but I hope anyone else having this issue can find the answer here